# Structured Data for SEO using Gatsby or a SPA

Tags: reactjs, seo, gatsby, json-ld, structured-data

Hello I am interested in adding the following JSON-LD structured data to my Gatsby Site. I have tagged React in this as the response in Gatsby is typically very low. What I would like to do is follow along the example here
 https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data

How do I add structured data to a Gatsby or a React site?

I am looking for both a static solution (i.e. for Contact Page) and a dynamic solution (i.e. for a Recipe Page ) to auto fill the values

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for creating and adding SEO is described in this [official Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/seo/#page-metadata).

You add an SEO component with React helmet:

```js
// src/components/SEO.js

const SEO = ({ title, description, image, pathname, article }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={query}
    render={({
      site: {
        siteMetadata: {
          defaultTitle,
          titleTemplate,
          defaultDescription,
          siteUrl,
          defaultImage,
          twitterUsername,
        }
      }
    }) => {
      const seo = {
        title: title || defaultTitle,
        description: description || defaultDescription,
        image: `${siteUrl}${image || defaultImage}`,
        url: `${siteUrl}${pathname || '/'}`,
      }
      return ()
    }}
  />
)
export default SEO
```

On the bottom you can find some example links. The documentation describes both solutions for static and dynamic meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your SEO component itself create two objects

First,

```
  const schemaOrgWebPage = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    url: siteUrl,
    headline: "Your Headline here",
    inLanguage: "en",
    mainEntityOfPage: siteUrl,
    description: "your description here",
    name: "your name here",
    author: {
      "@id": "author name",
    },
    copyrightHolder: {
      "@id": "copyright holder name",
    },
    copyrightYear: "2020",
    creator: {
      "@id": "creator name",
    },
    publisher: {
      "@id": "publisher name",
    },
    datePublished: "date of your publication",
    image: {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      url: "image url",
    },
  }
```

Second,

```
  const orgaCreator = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@id": `${siteUrl}`,
    "@type": "WebPage",
    address: {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      addressCountry: "put your country name",
      addressLocality: "put your locality name",
    },
    name: "your name here",
    alternateName: "your nick name",
    description: description || defaultDescription,
    url: siteUrl,
    email: "your email address",
    founder: "founder name",
    foundingDate: "founding date",
    foundingLocation: "founding location",
    image: {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      url: `${siteUrl}${image || defaultImage}`,
      height: "512",
      width: "512",
    },
    logo: {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      url: `${siteUrl}${image || defaultImage}`,
      height: "60",
      width: "60",
    },
    sameAs: [
      "https://www.facebook.com/put-your-user-id-here",
      "https://stackoverflow.com/put-your-user-id-here",
      "https://github.com/put-your-user-id-here",
      "https://www.instagram.com/put-your-user-id-here",
      "https://twitter.com/put-your-user-id-here",
      "https://www.linkedin.com/put-your-user-id-here",
    ],
  }
```

Then finally add this inside Helmet tag

```
<Helmet>
    <html lang="en" />
    ....
    ....
      <script type="application/ld+json">
            {JSON.stringify(schemaOrgWebPage)}
          </script>
          <script type="application/ld+json">{JSON.stringify(orgaCreator)} 
   </script>
</Helmet>
```

If you want to test your structured data, once your site is deployed goto
https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/ and put your website url in there, it will give you an insight on your structured data.